# To Make URL with GUID using C#

Tags: c#, iis, url-rewriting

I have a link in a web page on clicking it will redirect to the curl `http://localhost:60048/Transaction/Dashboard.aspx` which is the orginal url and my requirement is on clicking the link the orginal url should not be display in browser instead rewrite the url with guid to `http://localhost:60048/9982016a-90a7-421f-b705-4bffedd0de8a` so the it wont be readable.kindly help me on this.

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RewriteUrl">
          <match url="^Transaction/Dashboard" />          
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/Transaction/Dashboard?id={R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: Um, "Transaction/Dashboard.aspx" is shorter than "9982016a-90a7-421f-b705-4bffedd0de8a" (as well as much more readable of course). Please clarify the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet i  want url with guid after redirection

Comment: Okay, so this isn't actually about shortening at all... in which case you could presumably just hardcode the GUID you want going to the readable URL you want. I have to say that I can't see the appeal, going from a short and readable URL to a longer and unreadable one...

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually the url should not be a readable one. So i thought by removing Transaction/Dashboard.aspx and replace with guid so it can't be readable

Comment: Well as I say, you can just rewrite it explicitly. But it really does seem pretty hostile to users. You might want to edit your question to explain *why* you want to do this, given that it's a pretty odd requirement.

Comment: @jonSkeet I have edited my question to rewrite the url after redirection

Comment: What do you mean by "after redirection" in this case? What's redirecting? (Redirecting and rewriting are very different, and it's unclear where redirection comes in...) It's also still really unclear why you'd want to do this.

Comment: It's still *really* unclear - a button where? Why doesn't it redirect to the URL you actually want? I'm afraid I really can't help with such an unclear question, and I suspect others won't be able to either. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @JonSkeet please check my edited question.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what effect you want. Usually we all want the URL looks simple and readable. But according to your rewrite rules, the URL has become more complicated. So what you finally want to achieve? Can you give an example of what form you want the URL showing in browser.

Comment: I feel that your rewrite rules seem to be not completely correct. You can refer to the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module